# Extracting columns from dataframes in a list to produce a final, combined dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

Apologies, returning to `lists` and `dataframes` in `R` after a while, so have forgotten my way about. Suppose that I have several dataframes in a list:

```
d2<- data.frame(week=c("12th","13th","14th"),value=c(1,20,100))
d1<- data.frame(week=c("12th","13th","14th"),value=c(1,10,15))
d3<- data.frame(week=c("12th","13th","14th"),value=c(1,220,30))
dfList<- list(d1,d2,d3)

dfList
[[1]]
  week value
1 12th     1
2 13th    10
3 14th    15

[[2]]
  week value
1 12th     1
2 13th    20
3 14th   100

[[3]]
  week value
1 12th     1
2 13th   220
3 14th    30
```

And I would like to have a final dataframe with combined data, the shape of which is as follows

```
finalDf<- data.frame(week=c("12th","13th","14th"),value1=c(1,20,100),value2=c(1,10,15),value3=c(1,220,30))

  week value1 value2 value3
1 12th      1      1      1
2 13th     20     10    220
3 14th    100     15     30
```

How could I achieve the above form of data?
Also, what if my initial dataframes also have NAs, which I would like to remove prior to achieving the final form of data?

Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the cbind strategies, but they may fail if there are missing values, so I thought a merge approach should be illustrated:

```
 Reduce( function(x,y) merge(x, y, by="week"), dfList)
  week value.x value.y value
1 12th       1       1     1
2 13th      10      20   220
3 14th      15     100    30
```

If you wanted to keep all the potential NA values then perhaps adding an `, all.x=TRUE` argument would be needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
> cbind(dfList[[1]], lapply(dfList[2:3], `[`, "value"))
  week value value value
1 12th     1     1     1
2 13th    10    20   220
3 14th    15   100    30
```

It seems the numbering of your dataframes is not the same in your data setup and your intended result, but any version of this code (changing the relevant extraction indices in `[` and `[[`) will get you to your intended structure.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
 library(plyr)
 join_all(dfList, by="week")
 #  week value value value
 #1 12th     1     1     1
 #2 13th    10    20   220
 #3 14th    15   100    30
```

Also, works with `NA` Using @Frank's data

```
  res <- join_all(dfList, by="week")
  res
  #  week value value value
  #1 12th     1    NA     1
  #2 13th    10    NA   220
  #3 14th    15    NA    NA

  str(res)
 #'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
 # $ week : Factor w/ 3 levels "12th","13th",..: 1 2 3
 #$ value: num  1 10 15
 #$ value: logi  NA NA NA
 #$ value: num  1 220 NA  ##numeric columns
```

Comment: so simple! I am overjoyed for learning about so many different approaches! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are some very nice answers already, but here's another:

Step 1: Combine your data.frames into a long list:

```
dfDF <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

Step 2: Add a "time" variable that indicates the list from which the data came. There are a few ways to do that....

```
with(dfDF, ave(as.character(week), week, FUN = seq_along))
# [1] "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "3" "3" "3"

rep(sequence(length(dfList)), vapply(dfList, nrow, 1L))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

dfDF$time <- with(dfDF, ave(as.character(week), week, FUN = seq_along))
```

Step 3: Use `dcast` to go from "long" to "wide".

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dfDF, week ~ time, value.var = "value")
#   week  1   2   3
# 1 12th  1   1   1
# 2 13th 10  20 220
# 3 14th 15 100  30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(t(unique(t(do.call(cbind, dfList)))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#  week value value.1 value.2
#1 12th     1       1       1
#2 13th    10      20     220
#3 14th    15     100      30
```

If you want the `value` columns to be numeric instead of characters:

```
df[2:4] <- sapply(df[2:4], as.numeric)
df
#  week value value.1 value.2
#1 12th     1       1       1
#2 13th    10      20     220
#3 14th    15     100      30
```

Also, works with NAs:

```
d2<- data.frame(week=c("12th","13th","14th"),value=c(NA,NA,NA))
d1<- data.frame(week=c("12th","13th","14th"),value=c(1,10,15))
d3<- data.frame(week=c("12th","13th","14th"),value=c(1,220,NA))
dfList<- list(d1,d2,d3)

df <- data.frame(t(unique(t(do.call(cbind, dfList)))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#  week value value.1 value.2
#1 12th     1    <NA>       1
#2 13th    10    <NA>     220
#3 14th    15    <NA>    <NA>
```